# InteliJ -- Gradle 'test' project refresh failed Error:Error:Could not create parent directory for lock file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am new to Gradle, I am using InteliJ, just start a new project using using Gradle, when I try to refresh my build.gradle, it says

```
Gradle 'test' project refresh failed
    Error:Error:Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\gradle-2.7\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.5-rc-2-bin\ktl4k9rdug30mawecgppf5ms\gradle-3.5-rc-2-bin.zip.lck
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

this is my build.gradle

```
group 'com.maxinrui'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.6.RELEASE'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with your classpath, check your build path. if not set then you need to set. You can set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'`
and add `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip` into gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Then sync your project.